# getting different out put when passing object to a function having argument as reference type and when its class object type

Tags: c++

When i am passing object to a function having reference to the passing object , child class is getting called but when i am declaring the argument as object base class is getting called.  Below example  will be clear what is my doubt.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
protected:
    int i;
public:
    Base(int a)     { i = a; }
    virtual void display()
    { cout << "I am Base class object, i = " << i << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int j;
public:
    Derived(int a, int b) : Base(a) { j = b; }
    virtual void display()
    { cout << "I am Derived class object, i = "
           << i << ", j = " << j << endl;  }
};

// Global method, Base class object is passed by value
void somefunc (Base &obj)
{
    obj.display();
}

int main()
{
    Base b(33);
    Derived d(45, 54);
    somefunc(b);
    somefunc(d);  // Object Slicing, the member j of d is sliced off
    return 0;
}
```

O/P :I am Base class object, i = 33
I am Derived class object, i = 45, j = 54

if i am declaring "`void somefunc (Base obj)`"

then out put is
O/P:
I am Base class object, i = 33
I am Base class object, i = 33

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Program output which you have mentioned in `1st` case is just fine. This is because it is perfectly fine to assign objects of `Derived` class to reference of `Base` class. Nothing wrong in it! For second case, `void somefunc (Base obj)` , object slicing will take place if you pass object of `Derived` because copy-constructor of `Base` class will be called and it doesn't know anything about `Derived' so only part of`Base` will be taken from Derived's object.